# Checking for missing dependencies without installing an RPM

Tags: linux, perl, rpm

I want to build a script that downloads all missing packages but doesn't install them immediately.  To do so, I'm trying to get the list of the missing dependencies when installing a new RPM by using a Perl program.

I've tried using the **rpm -qpR** flag but it outputs all the requirements and not only the missing ones.

Next, I've tried using the **rpm -Uvh --test** flags but  can't get it to work - it outputs an empty string.

My Perl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$output="";
open(README, "rpm -Uvh ".$ARGV[0]." --test |") or die "Can't run program: $!\n";
while(<README>) {
    $output .= $_;
}
close(README);
print "OUTPPUT=".$output."\n";
```

I think the problem is that the output goes to **stderr** instead of **stdout**.

Tanks for your help!

Comment: try to run the command on prompt first so that you will be sure what is the expected output. other thing is rpm -Uvh is to upgrade package is that what you want. List of [commands](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/linux-rpm-cheat-sheet.php) which might help.

Comment: @SunilKartikey yea, i had a deep look at the man page, that's how I found the --test flag. The problem with only -Uvh is that it installs immediately while i want to find the dependencies without the actual installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use yum-downloadonly

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-downloadonly-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is what you thing it is,

```
open(README, "rpm -Uvh ".$ARGV[0]." --test 2>&1 |")
                                           ^^^^
                                         add this
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `rpm -qpR` and then looping over the results to see if the package is installed.

To do so grep the package name in `rpm -qa`.

This could work even though it's not the necessarily the best approach.

Comment: The problem with that is that it gives me the full dependencies and not just the missing ones. Any suggestions for a better approach?

Comment: That's what I meant when I said to grep in rpm -qa.

It shows you which packages are installed so you can bring the list down to only the packages that are missing.